# React Link tags, creating an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to use react link tags for my routing component in a website I am building.

I believe I am using the tags correctly as I am trying to use a prop (`product.title`) as the 'anchor' for this. I am unsure of what I am doing wrong as this is what appears on my [site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wh0N.png) (notice there is no `product.title` or p tag appearing). Clicking each box works perfectly as it routes based on `product.id`. I am just focused on creating a 'preview' of what each product will be. Any help would be amazing!

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
export default function ProductList({products,title}){
    return(
        <div className="product-list">
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {products.map((product) =>
                <div className="product-preview" key={product.id}>
                    <Link to = {`/products/${product.id}`}>
                        <h1>{product.title}</h1>
                        <p>here</p>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Long shot, but what is the doctype of the containing HTML document?

Comment: What does the product array look like?

Comment: @AdamThomas I am not sure where to find that, I have HTML as the doctype in my index.html

Comment: @zemaj it is a json file. I am able to access product.title outside of the Link tag, just for some reason doesnt show as an anchor

Comment: Can you post the whole doctype entry or screenshot the top of the HTML? I know this seems unrelated but in HTML4, nesting other elements like those in the <a> tag (which Link resolves to) is not allowed and would cause the browser not to display them.

Comment: Agree with @AdamThomas that you might not be able to nest the elements, I would consult docs or try it without the <h1> and <p> elements. You can create a react component that will wrap the Link if this is the case.  Seen here: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/component-reactcomponen